# Is the connection between elliptic curve and lattice unique?

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves

If I remember correctly, elliptic curve (over C) is isomorphic to a complex lattice, and they are connected by some technical stuff(Eisenstein series, j-invariant,...) But the whole process seems so artificial and I doubt if this is the only(or simplest) way to do this. Why is j-invariant so uglily defined? Can every invariant regarding complex lattice be represented by the j-invariant?

Comment: elliptic curves are not isomorphic to lattices, but to quotients of $\mathbb C$ over rank-two lattices. Conversely, every rank-two lattice in $\mathbb C$ gives rise to an elliptic curve. This process is not artificial at all, and the $j$-invariant is in fact a very natural object, since it provides an isomorphism between the moduli space of elliptic curves over $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C$. Moreover, it is a modular function , so it is very symmetric, in a suitable sense.